# ssh-keys not being saved after reboot OSX

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys, fish

Everytime I log to mi user and run `ssh-add -l` it returns `The agent has no identities.`

So I had to add this line to mi fish.config file:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_one and ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_two > /dev/null ^ /dev/null
```

I know it works but I want to evaluate first it they have been already added to the agent in order to prevent this line to run every time I open up a terminal tab.

PD: also if there's a different way to keep them consistently on the ssh agent I'll be glad to know, already tried adding them with the -K option and adding

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_one
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_two
```

to my `~/.ssh/config` and `~/.ssh/ssh_config` with no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to point out is your command

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_one and ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_two > /dev/null ^ /dev/null
```

doesn't do what you think it does. The fish `and` command is not syntactically the same as `&&`. It's a command. Which means it has to follow a semi-colon or be the first word on a line. So that should be

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_one; and ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_two > /dev/null ^ /dev/null
```

Also, throwing away stderr in this situation is risky. If you didn't do that you would have noticed the command wasn't doing what you thought. You should only throw away stderr when you know the command will emit error messages you know can be safely ignored.

The simplest, portable, way is to simply test whether one of the IDs is already registered with the ssh agent:

```
if status is-login
    if not ssh-add -l | grep -q $HOME/.ssh/id_one
        ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_one ~/.ssh/id_two
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot, tested it and is working like a charm. Since now I know it's working,  would be 'safe' to add `> /dev/null ^ /dev/null` to the `ssh-add` command?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to redirect the output to /dev/null? What if something breaks in the future? For example, what if you remove one of the private key files? Wouldn't you like to see an error reminding you to update that `ssh-add` command? It's your system so you're free to do what you want but I don't see the point in this situation of redirecting to /dev/null.

Comment: Guess you're right... I don't know what kind of obsession I have with keeping my terminal window as clean as possible.